# Unable to access Dictionary values in Template (object pk is the dict key)

Tags: django, dictionary, django-templates, django-views

I have a Django View that constructs a dictionary to a template. I have seen similar questions but no one shows how to access the dictionary value in the template using the object `pk` as the key (in my case the `key`s are `pk`s of the object).

View code that constructs the dict:

```
comment_uservote = {}
  if not current_logged_user.is_anonymous():
    for comment in comments_all:
        try:
            co_vote = Vote.objects.get(user=current_logged_user, comment=comment)
            comment_uservote[comment.id] = co_vote.vote
        except Vote.DoesNotExist:
            co_vote = ''
            comment_uservote[comment.id] = co_vote
```

I have also tried with `comment_uservote[str(comment.id)]` but this does not help either.

Template (that does not work):

```
{% for comment in comments %}
  {{comment_uservote.comment.pk}} <!--this does not work-->
{% enfor %}
```

However, the following works if I add any comment's `pk` to the `comment_uservote`.

Template (that works but if a direct substitution):

```
{% for comment in comments %}
  {{comment_uservote.16}} <!--this works-->
{% enfor %}
```

Appreciate your help. Please let me know if you need something more from me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this doesn't work, and the documentation doesn't imply that it should. You will need a custom tag or filter.

Comment: Fairly new to Django. Which one would be easier to implement between a tag and filter. Any hint specific to my situation would be beneficial since I have no clue where to start.

Comment: Is there any article you can point me to, that will give me a hint and helps in my case?