# Django cannot access cannot access a dicitionary passed in context using a variable created in the template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am learning Django by making a newsfeed website for practice. In my newsfeed page I want to display the number of likes on a post on the like button. See the two code blocks below -

> 1. views.py - Here I have put all my posts in all_posts and then has looped through the posts to get the count of total likes on this post from a Likes table in the model (If there is a better way please suggest) into the likes dictionary.

```
all_posts = NewsFeed.objects.all().order_by('time').reverse()
likes = {}
for post in all_posts:
    likes_count = Likes.objects.filter(newsfeed = post).count()
    likes[post.id] = likes_count

form = StatusForm()
context = {
    'name': name,
    'all_posts': all_posts,
    'statusForm': form,
    'likes': likes,
}
```

> 2. index.html - Here I want to display all the posts and a like button for each post which would also display the number of likes on the post. When I am manually trying to access the likes count {{ likes.4 }} it is displaying correct count for the fourth status Like(1) but when I try to access it like {{ likes.post_id }} it displays nothing Like(). Please help me out as I am new to this and also provide with the suggestions to do the same in a better way if there's any.

```
{% for post in all_posts %}
<div class="newsfeed-div">
    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    <pre>{{ post.user.name }}</pre>
    <pre>{{ post.time }}</pre>
    {% with post_id=post.id %}
        <a href="{% url 'newsfeed:likeStatus' post.id %}"><button>Like({{ likes.post_id }})</button></a>
        <a href="#"><button>Comment(0)</button></a>
    {% endwith %}
</div><hr/>
{% endfor %}
```

When I use something like:

```
{{ likes.4}}
```

I am getting the correct likes count for the 4th newsfeed but why

```
{{ likes.post_id }}
```

not working?

Please help me out and also provide your suggestions for accomplishing the same in a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django templates do not support indexing by a variable key. See [Unable to access Dictionary values in Template (object pk is the dict key)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5875894/unable-to-access-dictionary-values-in-template-object-pk-is-the-dict-key) for a similar question.

That being said, your problem could easily be solved by using

```
{{ post.likes_set.count }}
```

The `_set` suffix is a convention for the default name of a [`RelatedManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/relations/) that would return all the child records in a one-to-many relation (all the `likes` belonging to a given `post` for this example) and [`.count`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#count) returns the number of rows.